# How to set sql field value equal to another value in the same table

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains values for different locations where the `location id and the item number combination form the primary key`.  A lot of the items are the same in both locations when it comes to cost etc.  I am needing to fix one locations information that got changed by a user somehow.  I am looking for advice on how to set the value for `location 1 for item 1` to be the same as `location 2 item 1`.  I know how to do this if the value is in a different table, but I am not sure how to accomplish this when the values are in the same table.  Any advice will be greatly apprciated

Comment: plese show the structure of the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
UPDATE l1
SET COST = l2.COST
FROM TableA l1
INNER JOIN TableA l2 ON l2.Location = 2 AND l1.item = l2.item
WHERE l1.location = 1 and l1.item = 1
```

Answer (score 11):

I think you're looking for this:

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = col2
```

Sets "col1" to the value of "col2" in all rows of the table "table"

Answer (score 3):

if you want one column value set in same table other column value then use this query

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_1 = column_2
```

column_1 suppose this is blank in all record and
column_2 this column you want to put same value in column_1 
then use below example:

```
UPDATE customer SET `blank_column` = `student_name`
```

run query and blank_column can fill same as student_name value

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
UPDATE table t1 JOIN table t2
SET t1.col1 = t2.col1, t1.col2 = t2.col2, ...
WHERE t1.item_number = 1 and t1.location_id = 1
AND t2.item_number = 1 and t2.location_id = 2
```

Comment: this will throw unique key violation error based on OP's data and table structure

Comment: Right. His description of what he wants to change is confusing.

Comment: He is trying to update `location 1, item 1` columns to match `location 2, item 1` data.